# Is it possible to create a transactional merge table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql4

MySQL docs say that tables that use the MERGE storage engine can only union underlying MyISAM tables, which don't allow use of transactions.

Is there an alternative or workaround so that I can have a table that contains the data of several transactional tables in MySQL?

Also, MySQL 4... I know, I know, but it's what I'm stuck with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/ansi-diff-views.html) to accomplish this.  I'm not too sure if you need the full insert, update, delete functionality or if you just want to select from many tables.

Comment: Months later, best answer.  Thanks.